# A point on the unit circle that is not an n-th root of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Consider the set of complex numbers with absolute value 1. Some points on this set are n-th roots of unity. But there are points that aren't. Is there a closed-form expression for even one of those points which are not n-th roots of unity?

Comment: $\frac 35+\frac45i$ is not a root of $1$ and if recall correctly no element of $\Bbb Q[i]\cap S^1$ is a root of $1$ except $1,-1,i,-i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $n^\textrm{th}$ roots of unity are the values of the form $\zeta_{n,m} = e^{2\pi i m/ n}$ for integers $m,n$ where (if considering primitive roots) $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. So there are only countably many $n^\textrm{th}$ roots of unity, while the unit circle is an uncountable set.

So the question becomes can we represent any of those others in a closed form easily. And we can, we can represent any point on the unit circle as $e^{i \theta}$ so for any $\theta \neq 2\pi \frac{m}{n}$, then $e^{i\theta}$ will be a point on the unit circle that isn't a root of unity. So for example, we have $e^{ni}$ is on the unit circle but isn't a root of unity for any integer $n$.